# Requests library crashing on Python 2 and Python 3 with

Tags: python, exception, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse arbitrary webpages with the `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` libraries with this code:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
except Exception as error:
    return False

if response.encoding == None:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text) # This is line 809
else:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, from_encoding=response.encoding)
```

On most webpages this works fine. However, on some arbitrary pages (<1%) I get this crash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/parser.py", line 155, in has_css
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 809, in text
    content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace')
  TypeError: str() argument 2 must be str, not None
```

For reference, this is the relevent method of the requests library:

```
@property
def text(self):
    """Content of the response, in unicode.

    if Response.encoding is None and chardet module is available, encoding
    will be guessed.
    """

    # Try charset from content-type
    content = None
    encoding = self.encoding

    # Fallback to auto-detected encoding.
    if self.encoding is None:
        if chardet is not None:
            encoding = chardet.detect(self.content)['encoding']

    # Decode unicode from given encoding.
    try:
        content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace') # This is line 809
    except LookupError:
        # A LookupError is raised if the encoding was not found which could
        # indicate a misspelling or similar mistake.
        #
        # So we try blindly encoding.
        content = str(self.content, errors='replace')

    return content
```

As can be seen, I am not passing in an encoding when this error is thrown. **How am I using the library incorrectly, and what can I do to prevent this error?** This is on Python 3.2.3, but I can also get the same results with Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the server did not send an encoding for the content in the headers, and the `chardet` library was also not able to determine an encoding for the contents. You in fact deliberately test for the lack of encoding; why try to get decoded text if no encoding is available?

You can try to leave the decoding up to the `BeautifulSoup` parser:

```
if response.encoding is None:
   soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)
```

and there is *no* need to pass in the encoding to BeautifulSoup, since if `.text` does not fail, you are using Unicode and BeautifulSoup will ignore the encoding parameter anyway:

```
else:
   soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn! Using this code, I've parsed about 1000 URLs with no issues, so it looks like that is in fact the solution!

Comment: `.text` fails because no encoding was available from the server, and either you don't have `chardet` (which comes *with* `requests`, bundled) or `chardet` failed to determine an encoding. The latter has to make an educated guess and sometimes that fails.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, your insight is much appreciated!